# How to return a MemoryStream as an Excel file from IActionResult in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, memorystream, asp.net5

I'm working on an `Asp.Net Core` project targeted `.Net 5`.

I have this `ActionResult` :

```
     public async Task<ActionResult> ExportMarksForm(int testId)
            {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                // Some logic to Save the workbook as stream

                return File(stream, "application/ms-excel", "xxx.xlsx");
            }
```

**The problem:**
Everything works fine but when I downloaded the file I got an excel message that told me that the file is damaged, that is means an error happened or the file writing operation not complete.

I tried **break points** and I saw that the `stream` variable has `bytes`.

So, please how can I fix this issue? or if there is any other solution to return a `stream` as an Excel file please share it with me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed the Issue by using `FileStreamResult`:

```
return new FileStreamResult( stream , "application/ms-excel" )
                   {
                       FileDownloadName = "xxx.xlsx"
                   };
```